# How can I pass objects to ViewModels using NavigationService?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm, inversion-of-control

The project I am working on is a desktop based WPF application. I have implemented the MVVM pattern in it. Also I am using Unity IoC and the Repository Pattern in it.

I have a problem in a master details type scenario. I navigate to the details Page(I have used IoC to expose the NavigationService in the ViewModel) but I dont know how can I get the employeeID in the EmployeeDetails ViewModel without breaking the MVVM pattern. I don't want to write anything in code behind.

Any pointers will be very helpful.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you achieve this by exposing a property `CurrentEmployee` in your `EmployeeMasterViewModel`. This property is data bound to the currently selected item in the master list.
You then bind the controls of the details page to the properties of `CurrentEmployee`.

Comment: This could be possible if both master and details viewmodel are nested somehow in a class.. but what i am talking about is two different/seperate Views having different ViewModels, i am navigating from one view to another using NavigationService.

Comment: Can't you use [this overload of Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591042.aspx) to pass in the currently selected employee?

Comment: no because i can't refer to View's Class from my ViewModel, just to preserve separation of concerns and MVVM pattern. i can only navigate to page using a uri.

Comment: There is another overload that accepts an Uri as first parameter and an arbitrary object as second parameter...

Comment: yup i have also tried that.. but unfortunately i am unable to get e.ExtraData at my details page. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a54e19b8-ee1d-4e2c-81cb-760e2c3264df/ this explains that problem.. and seems no mvvm oriented solution there