# Sharing session data between frames and support load/restore state

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

Let's say that I have a list in my main frame in a windows store app with session data. When I click an item a new frame is open where I could edit the data.

How do I properly share session data between the frames, and how do I save and restore session data so that the references between the objects are intact?

I know that I could send an object as parameter when a new frame is created. I also know how to save/restore session data. I just don't how to solve this :).

Comment: Are you looking to solve this for wp7, wp8, or winrt? Because they are very different. And I don't think this applies to WPF apps either.

Comment: Currently I'm developing an application for windows desktop (where this problem doesn't exist) and windows rt just for learning. Windows phone may be a later project, but I want to design my app correctly so I could add support for this without any major changes. So all platforms are interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use NavigationService to send data to new frames as mentioned in the option below. it is more like sending keyvalur pairs as uri parameters:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?parameter1=p1&parameter2=p2", UriKind.Relative));
```

To get value:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);  
    string parameterValue = NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter"];  
}
```

http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-pass-data-between-pages-in-windows-phone-alternatives

Also if you want to share complex objects you might need to create nested viewmodels but if you don't have luxury to nest viewmodels due to nature of views then you might need to create a static app cache to use a medium to persist/share object among frames.

Comment: Ok, I was afraid of that :(. I have an idea with a global hashtable where I put all objects that are shared in the application and passing the ids as parameters to the views. I assume I could save the table when the app I suspended. All examples I have looked at are using hard coded data which doesn’t help me :(. This one for instance (which is pretty good except for that minor detail :) http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-master---detail-navigation-with-repository-pattern

Comment: this is correct, actually in past i have also faced the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329557/how-can-i-pass-objects-to-viewmodels-using-navigationservice . so far static/global repository is the solution.

Comment: Now I finally have something that works. Was most annoys me is that I haven’t found any example of these. Everyone is using static data that never change which is much easier. This makes me feel that I’m doing something wrong :-(.

Comment: :) there is nothing wrong actually it is just a matter of find the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Storing global references to objects isn't all that tricky. You can just have a static holder that does or doesn't have the responsibility to persist them. Oh, something like this:

```
public interface IViewModel { }
public class ViewModelOne : IViewModel { }
public class ViewModelTwo : IViewModel { }
public class ViewModelThree : IViewModel { }
public static class GlobalObjects
{
    private static ViewModelOne viewModelOne = null;
    public static ViewModelOne ViewModelOne
    {
        get { return Get<ViewModelOne>(ref viewModelOne); }
        set { Set(ref viewModelOne, value); }
    }

    private static T Get<T>(ref T storage) where T : IViewModel, new()
    {
        if (storage != null)
            return storage;
        try
        {
            var json = Load(typeof(T).ToString());
            return storage = Deserialize<T>(json);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new T();
        }
    }

    private static void Set<T>(ref T storage, T value) where T : IViewModel
    {
        if (storage?.Equals(value))
            return;
        try
        {
            var json = Serialize(value);
            Save(json, typeof(T).ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Save(string.Empty, typeof(T).ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Save(string value, string key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static string Load(string key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static T Deserialize<T>(string obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Best of luck!
// Jerry

Comment: That was pretty elegant :-). I may try that approach next time I encounter this problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some inspiration from Shoaib Shaikh I decided to do a global repository. Please review this cause I barely know what I’m doing :-).

I have three classes. All classes use DataContract so it’s easy to serialize. First PersonViewModel which is pretty straight forward:

```
[DataContract()]
public class PersonViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    #region Name property

    [DataMember()]
    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue(ref _Name, value, () => Name);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Second is the PersonListViewModel . Each PersonViewModel is stored in a global hash table with a string id. This class taking care of the ID:s. By calling RefreshPersonCollection the person list is rebuild from the global objects. Quite clumsy, it’s better to get the persons on request but I’m too tired to solve that right now :-).

```
[DataContract()]
public class PersonListViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    [DataMember()]
    private List<string> PersonIds = new List<string>();

    public PersonListViewModel()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>();

        CreateDefaultData();
    }

    public void CreateDefaultData()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            string personid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string personname = "Person " + personid;
            PersonViewModel person = new PersonViewModel(personname);

            PersonIds.Add(personid);
            Persons.Add(person);
            SharedObjects.Instance.Objects[personid] = person;
        }
    }

    public void RefreshPersonCollection()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>();

        foreach (string personid in PersonIds)
        {
            Persons.Add((PersonViewModel)SharedObjects.Instance.Objects[personid]);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> Persons{ get; set; }
}
```

Third class is my global repository. Also quite straight forward I think. All PersonViewModels and all PersonListViewModel is stored in this repository.

```
[DataContract()]
public class SharedObjects
{
    public static SharedObjects Instance;

    public SharedObjects()
    {
        Objects = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        Objects["mainviewmodel"] = new PersonListViewModel();
    }

    [DataMember()]
    private Dictionary<string, Object> _Objects;

    public Dictionary<string, Object> Objects
    {
        get { return _Objects; }
        set { _Objects = value; }
    }
}
```

In my Windows store application I have a SuspensionManager that I have modified it slightly to serialize and deserialize my global repository.

First change was to add my new types to known types to be serialized. I don’t like this, would prefer that the classes could do this themselves somehow (which is possible as far as I understand it).

```
static SuspensionManager()
{
         _knownTypes.Add(typeof(SharedObjects));
         _knownTypes.Add(typeof(PersonListViewModel));
         _knownTypes.Add(typeof(PersonViewModel));
}
```

Second change is in SaveAsync to make sure the global data is saved. Just one line was added:

```
            //I added this:
            _sessionState["globalobjects"] = SharedObjects.Instance;

            // Serialize the session state synchronously to avoid asynchronous access to shared
            // state
            MemoryStream sessionData = new MemoryStream();
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), _knownTypes);
            serializer.WriteObject(sessionData, _sessionState);
```

Third change is in RestoreAsync.

```
            // Get the input stream for the SessionState file
            StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(sessionStateFilename);
            using (IInputStream inStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
            {
                // Deserialize the Session State
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), _knownTypes);
                _sessionState = (Dictionary<string, object>)serializer.ReadObject(inStream.AsStreamForRead());
            }

            //I added this:
            if (_sessionState.ContainsKey("globalobjects"))
                SharedObjects.Instance = (SharedObjects) _sessionState["globalobjects"];
```

This feels manageable but any suggestions for improvements are appreciated :-). Will this work in Windows Phone as well (except for SuspensionManager, but I guess it's something similar on that platform)?